# Create/Read files with Python in Graal VM

Tags: java, python, file, graalvm, graalpython

Im working with Graal VM, using combined languages like Java and Python. I have a problem when try to execute Python sintax to read/create files using context.eval().

I use this code using **Graalpython** in terminal:

```
out_file = File.new("cadena.txt", "w+")
out_file.puts("write your stuff here")
out_file.close
```

and works, but when I tried to run a code to read the file in context.eval() with Java:

```
codigoPython += "fichw = open('cadena.txt','r')";
codigoPython += "fichw.read() ";
codigoPython += "fichw.close() ";
Value filecontent = context.eval("python", codigoPython);
```

it throws me this error:

*PermissionError: (1, Operation not permitted, cadena.txt, None, None)*

I also tried running it using sudo and sudo su but it gives me the same error. Does anyone know why this happened?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give your context permission to do IO:

```
Context context = Context.newBuilder("python").allowIO(true).build();
```

For experimenting/prototyping it may be useful to allow everything:

```
Context context = Context.newBuilder("python").allowAllAccess(true).build();
```

Comment: Where is doc about all needed and possible configuration of Context?

Comment: This is probably what you are looking for: https://www.graalvm.org/reference-manual/embed-languages/?

Comment: Well, that doc is not that clear what must passed to context to enable some specific Python functionality.
I'd go with `allowAllAccess(true)` until there any hints what exactly is needed for Python.